# __eq__ on super objects

Tags: python, python-2.7, super

Following piece of code works fine in Python 3 (3.5.2) but raises an `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__eq__'` in Python 2 (2.7.12)

```
class Derived(int):

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return super(Derived, self).__eq__(other)


a, b = Derived(1024), Derived(1729)
print(a == b)
```

Python 3 behaviour is expected. I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work in Python 2.

Please note that this question is not a duplicate of ['super' object has no attribute '__eq__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381318/super-object-has-no-attribute-eq)

Comment: Because in Python 2 `int` doesn't have rich comparison operators (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809932/python-why-does-the-int-class-not-have-rich-comparison-operators-like-lt)). Python 3 implements rich comparison operators as `__cmp__` was depracated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening here is that the super class for `Derived` is `int`. In Python 2, `int` does not implement rich comparison operators like `__lt__`, `__gt__`, or `__eq__` as it uses `__cmp__` instead. However, `__cmp__` is not supported in Python 3, so `int` implements rich comparison operators like `__lt__`, `__gt__`, and `__eq__` in Python 3. So, in `Derived` in Python 2, `super.__eq__` does not exist because `int.__eq__` does not exist in Python 2.

Comment: I kind of assumed `int` implements `__eq__` from this `>>> int.__eq__ <method-wrapper '__eq__' of type object at 0x000000001E298C40>` but now I tried `int.__eq__(1, 2)` and got an error. `int.__eq__(0)` returns `NotImplemented` Can you expand on how all this works?

Comment: In python 2 `int.__eq__` is comparing the `int` class to another class, not comparing `int`s. So `int.__eq__(int)` will be true, but `int.__eq__(float)` will be false.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: No worries. Python 2 has some weird features in it related to this. Python 3 tried to standardize a lot better.